# view page's link in the same way fo FB

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, html, user-interface

we are trying to create website based on RSS feeds collected from different sites, and
  viewing RSS links in the same way of the facebook is one of requirements. so how it does?

[Facebook link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsU7I.png)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You may use this tutorial to build facebook type [link extractor](http://www.redsunsoft.com/2011/01/parse-link-like-facebook-with-jquery-and-php/)